# Laravel Eloquent: How to select not attached records in many to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between users and books. How to select all books, that are not attached to a specific user?

The easy, but ugly, way is to load all books, load all books attached to the user and diff the collections. But there has to be an elegant way, I just can not figure it out.

It could be done using the query builder and a some joining, but how to achieve it using eloquent?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `whereDoesntHave()` for that:

```
$userId = 1;
$books = Book::whereDoesntHave('users', function($q) use ($userId){
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

This method allows you to filter the query by the existence (`whereHas`) (or in this case non-existence: `whereDoesntHave`) of a related model.

---

In case you want all books that aren't assigned to any user it's a bit simpler:

```
$books = Book::doesntHave('users')->get();
```

Comment: You don't really need the closure in this case either but good to note that it can take one. You can also use 'Book::doesntHave($relationship, $condition = 'and', Closure $closure)` if you want more control over the where statement.

Comment: @DavidBarker Yes you do need the closure? Without it you can only filter for books that are assigned to any or no user.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Which is what the OP asked... all books that aren't attached to any user... no closure needed for this to work unless he wanted to filter it by the currently logged in user... that's when the closure would be necessary. Either way, good answer.

Comment: @DavidBarker I'm pretty this is about the currently logged in user. Quote: "load all books attached to the user and diff the collections". (*the* user). Anyways, I'm sure rootman will clear that up soon ;)

Comment: I was referring to a specific user, will update my question because I phrased it kind of badly, so the answer @lukasgeiter gave was actually what I was looking for.

Comment: @rootman Knew it! :P. Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer to mark your question as solved :)